# Customer facing ID for hibernate entity

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

My application requires that I generate a "customer facing ID" for an entity. The ID has to uniquely identify the entity for reference by the customer, but cannot be the primary key used in the DB. It also must not be a sequential value so it's harder to predict.

I've landed on creating a permutation of the ID field for my entity, and I have that part working. The problem I have now is that I'm not sure of the best way to handle this in Hibernate since I cannot generate my permutation until the ID is generated.

I'm using Oracle as the database and a sequence is used to generate the ID. Is there a way to capture the ID when it is retrieved from the sequence, create my permutation, and set the value on the entity before it is inserted into the DB? Or, am I stuck saving the entity, setting the permutation value, and then updating the entity?

Also, I'm open to better suggestions on how to meet these requirements?

Comment: You could simply use a [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). I don't see how a permutation of a sequentially-generated ID could be hard to predict.

Comment: Why even bother tying it to a permutation of the ID? In the past I have used a randomly generated alphanumeric id (aaaa-111-bbbb), which was deemed more "readable" than say, a GUID. Depending on structure and length, it can give you billions of combinations which can significantly reduce the likely hood of a collision.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an important requirement. The ID has to be numeric and 11 characters (leading zeros are OK). The ID would be used as a reference and 32 alphanumeric characters was deemed too complicated. Otherwise, a UUID or a hash would work great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual column in 11g.  First, create a basic function that will generate an md5 hash based on the fields you believe should determine your identifier:

```
create or replace function get_naddr_hash(i_string in varchar2, i_uppercase in number default 0)
return varchar2 deterministic
as
    l_string varchar2(32767);
begin
    l_string := substr(i_string, 1, 32767);
    if (i_uppercase > 0) then
        l_string := upper(l_string);
    end if;

  return rawtohex(
    DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash (
        UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (l_string, 'AL32UTF8'),
        2)
    );
end;
```

Note that this function requires that dbms_crypto is already setup on the db.

Then create (or recreate via ctas) the table with a virtual column using this function:

```
create table tst_tab
(
naddr_hash as (get_naddr_hash(trim(username)||trim(address1)||trim(city)||trim(state), 1)),
username varchar2(100) not null,
address1 varchar2(100) not null,
address2 varchar2(100),
city varchar2(100) not null,
state varchar2(2) not null,
zip varchar2(9),
phone varchar2(20)
);
```

Here I think that username, address1, city, state will be the determining fields.  After this setup, you should be good to go.

```
insert into tst_tab
(
username, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone
) values
(
'Joe Smith', '123 Main St', 'Ste 100', 'Denver', 'CO', '12345', '5551212'
);

insert into tst_tab
(
username, address1, address2, city, state
) values
(
'JOE SMITH', '123 Main St', 'Ste 101', 'Denver', 'CO'
);
```

These 2 will have the same naddr_hash.  The following will have a different hash:

```
insert into tst_tab
(
username, address1, address2, city, state
) values
(
'JANE SMITH', '123 Main St', 'Ste 101', 'Denver', 'CO'
);
```

Looking at the data:

```
NADDR_HASH  USERNAME
2ADCBCAC3A26ED5BD189351B84BFA412    Joe Smith
2ADCBCAC3A26ED5BD189351B84BFA412    JOE SMITH
C56D5007C89284892FDF03A96C5E15E0    JANE SMITH
```